# Angular controller.js aggregate method with $group

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mean-stack

I'm working on mean stack application. Is it possible to use if else condition inside $group?

Below is my code.

I need to use if else condition inside $group to show multiple values.
I'm having a hard time to get it done

```
exports.allSum = function(req,res) {

   borrower.aggregate([

   { $match: { $and: [ { state:req.params.state }] },

 },
 { 
   $group:
   { _id : {state:"$state"},
   sumInsured : { $sum: {$toDouble: "$sumInsured" }},
 
 }
 }
 ])

  .then((ress) => {console.log(ress)
  res.send(ress)
  });
};
```

Comment: That has nothing to do with Angular. Looks like pieces of NodeJS code.

Answer (score 0):

That has nothing to do with Angular. Looks like pieces of NodeJS code.

Furthermore the $and operator expects two arguments so you can ommit it here. Just try to debug your aggregation query via Terminal and console.log.

Or whats a also a good way is to develop needed aggregation queries in

[MongoDB Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/compass)

Just connect to your database, select the collection and choose tab **Aggregations**. You can then start developing your pipeline step by step and see the results.